# Writing to a file with context - Android

Tags: android, file, android-context

I created a button which should write the selected item from two dropdown-spinners into a txt-file.

To do this I am using this method:

```
    public static void save(Context ctx) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {

        fos = ctx.openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(MyActivity.klasse);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my onClickListener:

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                String text = sp_jahrgang.getSelectedItem().toString() + sp_klasse.getSelectedItem().toString();
                System.out.println("JAHRGANG:"+text);

                MyActivity.klasse = text;
                System.out.println("TEST:"+MyActivity.klasse);
                save();
        }
    });
```

The problem is that I do not really understand the concept of "context". I do not know what kind of context I have to use. What do I have to put into the brackets for the method save?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: try this--> save(getActivityContext());

Comment: If you want to know more about context then read this nice article.
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the context of the activity in the brackets of `save` method. While using this method you need to pass context in following manner,

- If you are accessing the method from fragment then pass `getActivity()` inside the bracket

  i.e. `save(getActivity());`
- If you are calling this method from any activity then you can simply put `this`(not very safe to store reference to context but good enough for many tasks) or `getApplicationContext()` in the brackets.

  i.e. `save(getApplicationContext())`

Comment: It's "not very safe" to store a reference to a Context, which is an Activity Context, but in general it's OK to use it as a parameter to a function.